# PHP paging from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, paging

I have problem with my paging PHP script.
First page works perfectly, but next pages are blank.
Config.php include database setting like host etc.
Please help me solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
include 'config.php';
mysql_connect($iplogow, $userlogow, $haslologow) or die("Mysql error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($bazalogow)or die("Błąd bazy danych: " . mysql_error());


        echo '<br>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="500px">
               <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>table1</th>
                    <th>table2</th>
                <th>table3</th>
                <th>table4</th>
                <th>table5</th>
                <th>table6</th>
                <th>table7</th>
                     </tr></thead>';


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT Count(id) FROM `logi`");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $count_users = $row[0];

        $per_page = 10;


        $pages = ceil($count_users / $per_page);


        $current_page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : (int)clear($_GET['page']);


        if($current_page < 1 || $current_page > $pages) {
            $current_page = 1;
        }


        if($count_users > 0) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `logi` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ".($per_page*($current_page-1)).", ".$per_page);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['nick'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row['ip'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['password'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['productid'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['client'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['hour'].'</td>
                </tr>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Niestety nie znaleziono żadnych ataków.</td>
            </tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';


        if($pages > 0) { 
            echo '<p>';
            if($pages < 11) {
                for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                    if($i == $current_page) {
                        echo '<b>['.$current_page.']</b> ';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$i.'">['.$i.']</a> ';
                    }
                }
            } elseif($current_page > 10) {
                echo '<a href="ataki.php?page=1">[1]</a> ';
                echo '<a href="ataki.php?page=2">[2]</a> ';
                echo '[...] ';
                for($i = ($current_page-3); $i <= $current_page; $i++) {
                    if($i == $current_page) {
                        echo '<b>['.$current_page.']</b> ';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$i.'">['.$i.']</a> ';
                    }
                }
                for($i = ($current_page+1); $i <= ($current_page+3); $i++) {
                    if($i > ($pages)) break;
                    if($i == $current_page) {
                        echo '<b>['.$current_page.']</b> ';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$i.'">['.$i.']</a> ';
                    }
                }
                if($current_page < ($pages-4)) {
                    echo '[...] ';
                    echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.($pages-1).'">['.($pages-1).']</a> ';
                    echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$pages.'">['.$pages.']</a> ';
                } elseif($current_page == ($pages-4)) {
                    echo '[...] ';
                    echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$pages.'">['.$pages.']</a> ';
                }
            } else {
                for($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++) {
                    if($i == $current_page) {
                        if($i > ($pages)) break;
                        echo '<b>['.$current_page.']</b> ';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$i.'">['.$i.']</a> ';
                    }
                }
                if($pages > 12) {
                    echo '[...] ';
                    echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.($pages-1).'">['.($pages-1).']</a> ';
                    echo '<a href="ataki.php?page='.$pages.'">['.$pages.']</a> ';
                } elseif($pages == 12) {
                    echo '[...] ';
                    echo '<a href="ataki.php?page=12">[12]</a> ';
                }
            }
            echo '</p>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: What has recently been changed? What have you tried to solve your problem? little more info would be appreciated

Comment: This is script from internet :( I only change database pass, and table design (bootstrap). P.S when I type myserver.com/script.php?page=1 there is blank page too. myserver.com/script.php works perfectly...

Comment: Have you included the `clear()` function? Look at line: `$current_page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : (int)clear($_GET['page']);` If you have not included the function then you will get a fatal error in the execution of the script. Try to remove the clear() all together and see what happens, the changed line should be `$current_page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];`

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the `clear()` function?

Look at line: `$current_page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : (int)clear($_GET['page']);`

If you have not included the function then you will get a fatal error in the execution of the script. Try to remove the clear() all together and see what happens, the changed line should be

`$current_page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];`